# Cygwin cygdrive out of sync with filesystem

Tags: windows, cygwin

I'm trying to copy files to C:\Windows\System32 using cygwin bash. When I copy files into this folder, they appear when I run `ls` in the directory, but explorer.exe doesn't show these files, and cmd.exe doesn't show these files either.

What's happening? I feel like this will lead to undefined behavior, as I'm playing around with DLLs.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting them here instead:

```
/cygdrive/c/Windows/Sysnative
```

It may be related to system redirection. See http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-03/msg00842.html